# Join 3 tables in Yii 2

Tags: sql, database, join, yii2

I am working on a Yii 2 project. I have 3 tables:

1) Student Data Table

- **student_data_id**
- last_name
- first_name

2) Student Table

- **student_id**
- **student_data_id**
- class_id

3) Scores table

- **student_id**

From the scores table, I need to access the name of the student. In other words, I need to retrieve the last and first name of the student from the Student Data table using the **student_id**. I am familiar with joining tables but I don't know how to do this syntactically in Yii2. I hope I am clear and thank you in advance.

**Edit**
I also have 3 models of each table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `Scores` model, create the following relationship:

```
public function getStudentData() {
    return $this->hasOne(StudentData::className(), ['student_data_id' => 'student_data_id'])
        ->viaTable('student', ['student_id' => 'student_id']);
}
```

Comment: What is the meaning of the Filter there sir? Is it a model?

Comment: Sorry, I extracted the code from an example and I forgot to change that. Updated.

Comment: I get the logic of your answer sir. But I got Unknown Property Error on scores.student_id

Comment: Is your table called `scores`? is the field called `student_id`?

Comment: Yes Sir. I am sure with the naming. I also triple check the spelling. Based on the logic of the answer it should be right. There's something wrong maybe in the syntax